# How to make a countdown timer run in background in android?

Tags: android

I am revoking a timer in android using intent now if i want to put that timer in a background when user clicks on directly back button then how do i do that? and then when i see background apps running it should be working and can be brought to front.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that if you define the counter in your Activity, the counter is bound to the Activity life-cycle. In order to workaround this, you can create your counter in a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) and just visualize the value in Activity.

There are also several techniques which you can use when defining the counter inside the Activity. Using [SystemClock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html) to track the time in your Activity in onStart() and onStop() for example, you can manually calculate the difference between those two values and adjust accordingly your counter.

Comment: Hey ya hovanessyan thax for the answer but can u send me a sample of it cause i am actually nt getting this Service kinda thing and moreover i am not so experienced.mail id :- tirath9792@gmail.com